How do I increase the speed of an object inside my java processing app without sacrificing the frames
Okay so I am learning how to make games and stuff in java and I am using processing in that i am trying to generate a ellipse that will move constantly when fired, how I am animating is in draw() function I check for the condition when it should be fired and when the condition is true I draw the ellipse and change it new coordinates constantly. Currently my game is running at 30 fps and when I change the ellipse coordinates by small margin it moves slow but since the subsequent coordinates where ball will generate is so close it will generate close giving this slow but smooth animation, contrary to make it faster I have to increase the coordinates which give the fast but choppy animation. I am so lost as to how we actually make it faster without compromising the animation quality.
my structure looks like this
public float speed = 100;
public static final int FPS = 30;

public void draw() {
  // conditions to check
  if (tank.isTankfired()) {
    removeprojectile(tank.projectilestartX(), tank.projectilestartY());
    fill(255, 0, 0); // Set the fill color to red
    ellipse(tank.projectilestartX(), tank.projectilestartY(), 10, 10); 
    tank.setprojectilestartX(tank.projectilestartX()+speed/FPS);
    tank.setprojectilestartY(tank.projectilestartY()-speed/FPS);
  }
}

with this method it changes the x and y coordinate constantly and if I increase the speed it makes the distance between the next ellipse whereever it will be drawn more rather than generating it faster and since program is running at 30 fps it now looks choppy. I am new learning processing so any guidance to how it is actually handled would be grateful.

The trick is to not tie your physics to "frames" or "frames per second" but to actual time, where you measure the time between frames using millis() and then update your positions based on how much actual "clock time" passed. You can then scale that value by a factor to either effect a speed up, or slow down. (Also, note that right now your sketch is not running at 30 FPS at all: without a call to frameRate(), Processing runs at 60 fps by default)

It may be helpful to get an answer if you provide context for the code like the actual graphics framework and packages used. Edit the question to add details and the tags.

@aled. There is no package. The OP is using Processing. I think it's a derivative of Java. I hadn't played with it in years, so I could be wrong. It was a fun little thing years ago. It looks like it has grown.

Then is it a Java question at all?

I asked a similar question on meta about Android a long time ago because people would always use the Java tag with the Android tag. I got so many downvotes that I deleted the question. I think over time, less people have used both at the same time. That could be due to Kotlin, though. They are making Kotlin so different that, at some point, it will not be able to be a directive of Java. I think that's their goal after the lawsuit.

I want to add that there is also a free book that is great for learning stuff like this. I used it a while back when I was playing with Processing. Title: The Nature of Code: Simulating Natural Systems with Processing. I also used it and translated the code to JavaFX. It was fun and helped me learn about physics and practice my JavaFX.

@SedJ601 thank you brother, the book you recommended actually helped the error, it was related to how I was calculating the tanks position inside the main draw() loop (which itself is called for 60 fps, too much calculations slowing my program)

If I read the code correctly:

the projectile is tightly coupled to tank
the projectile's position is updated only when tank is fired.

If that's the case you want to update the projective position independently:

when the tank is fired you create a new projectile instance at the tank's position
from then on it's the projectile's job to update its position in that direction.
unless you want your tank to use a single projectile, you might want to create an array or ArrayList of Projectile objects to manage them.

These answers may help:
1,
2
(Also, I'm not 100% convinced setting the projectile's velocity as +/- speed/FPS is what you want (as they will always go in the same direction). Have a look at the two answers and how vx/vy is updated and used)

In the Star example code, they use frameCount / someDouble. My guess is that you should be able to do something similar.
Example Code:
/**
 * Star
 * 
 * The star() function created for this example is capable of drawing a
 * wide range of different forms. Try placing different numbers into the 
 * star() function calls within draw() to explore. 
 */

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
}

void draw() {
  background(102);
  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width*0.2, height*0.5);
  rotate(frameCount / 200.0);
  star(0, 0, 5, 70, 3); 
  popMatrix();
  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width*0.5, height*0.5);
  rotate(frameCount / 400.0);
  star(0, 0, 80, 100, 40); 
  popMatrix();
  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width*0.8, height*0.5);
  rotate(frameCount / -100.0);
  star(0, 0, 30, 70, 5); 
  popMatrix();
}

void star(float x, float y, float radius1, float radius2, int npoints) {
  float angle = TWO_PI / npoints;
  float halfAngle = angle/2.0;
  beginShape();
  for (float a = 0; a < TWO_PI; a += angle) {
    float sx = x + cos(a) * radius2;
    float sy = y + sin(a) * radius2;
    vertex(sx, sy);
    sx = x + cos(a+halfAngle) * radius1;
    sy = y + sin(a+halfAngle) * radius1;
    vertex(sx, sy);
  }
  endShape(CLOSE);
}

First Run Values:
rotate(frameCount / 400.0); - rotate(frameCount / 400.0); - rotate(frameCount / -100.0);

Second Run Values:
rotate(frameCount / 20.0); - rotate(frameCount / 75.0); - rotate(frameCount / -50.0);

